# Create read-only files on SMB share

Tags: file-permissions, smb

I have a home server set up with SMB shares. Those shares are actually external HDD's with NTFS connected to the server.

My question is, how do i make it so that users can create or delete files on SMB shares but can't modify already existing files (e.g. make all files created read-only)?

Comment: There may be some advanced configuration options of which I'm not aware that will allow this setup, but an easier solution would be to create a separate [share] where people can write (some sub-folder).

Comment: well, the main point of such set up is to prevent prevent worms and such from corrupting legitimate files on SMB shares while still allowing creating new files and deleting all other files.

Comment: If you can delete, you can write.